# Object is modified implicitly in one method and used by another

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have two methods `meth1` and `meth2`. `meth1` takes in an input of a set `set1`, returns a value, and also modifies `set1`.

Now `meth2` uses this `set1` to compute another return value.

The issue I see with this code is that the set modification is implicit and would be missed by a coder who is not careful enough.

I could do all the operations in a single method, but the working of both the methods is different enough to put them in different methods. Also a single method would be very long.

So given that I have to use two methods here, what is the best way to avoid the implicit modifications? What is the best practise to deal with this situation?

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

---

Method signatures:

`meth1`:

```
private List<CustomObject> meth1(List<CustomObjectOnWhichOperationIsPerformed> lst,
Set<AnotherCustomObject> set1, Map<String, AnotherCustomObject> mp) {
// Iterate on lst, call mp and remove AnotherCustomObject entities from set1
}
```

`meth2`:

```
private List<CustomObject> meth2(Set<AnotherCustomObject> set1) {
// Iterate on set1 to create the list
}
```

Comment: Does the change of the set have to be visible outside of method 1? If not, create a defensive copy of the set that has been passed and work on that only. If the changes are needed outside of that method, i.e. as a result, then you basically have 2 options: 1) create the copy and return it normally (you might need to wrap the current return value and the set in a new return type) or 2) try to express the fact that the parameter is changed in the method and parameter names and add some JavaDoc to add details.

Comment: Yes the changes are required outside the method. So I too could think of these options only. Currently going with the second option to add JavaDocs.

Comment: Can you share some details on those 2 methods, e.g. their signature? This might help make more specific suggestions.

Comment: @Thomas Sure. Will add the signature.

Comment: Can you add 2 more things for now? 1 - describe the return value of `meth1`: how is it related to the input, what does it represent and 2 - if possible add the real method and parameter names, changing them might already help with conveying what's happening (unless you can't share in which case you'd be on your own to figure out a meaningful name - just think about what you would imply with certain names.)

Comment: Another thought: could you extract the code into a class that only deals with that operation? That way you'd reduce the risk of having another coder to modify or access the code, especially since the methods seem to be private. Adding JavaDocs might then help those that actually _have_ to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this problem be approached differently? It looks like a violation of the single responsibility principle. The first method returns a value but also modifies the argument passed to it.

Break the first method up into two methods

1. Modify the set (explicitly)
2. handle the logic for getting the first return value

Then the last step

3. compute another return value

Comment: This looks good. The operation is basically a loop, and I am removing elements from the set. So the logic is tightly bound to the set modification. So I would anyhow require the logic part to return some collection that can be used to recreate the set. Any pointers to solve that?

Comment: Why do you have to do it this way? Why are the methods private? Take a look at the design of the whole thing, if this were a block diagram of black boxes, can you arrange the boxes such that you have one input and one output for each box?

Comment: Methods are private as they are not being used anywhere else in the code. Is this not the standard way to do this?

For the block diagram thing, sure. That sounds useful.